How to prevent a SIGABRT from event_base_new() when "Too many files open"
We're using libevent 1.4.14.
In our production environment, we've found that our process crashes with a SIGABRT from libevent when the host runs out of a file descriptors.
Consider the following
#include <event.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct rlimit rl;
  rl.rlim_cur = rl.rlim_max = 400; // artificially limit number of fds
  int ret = setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl);
  if (ret) {
    int errno_ = errno;
    std::cerr << "unable to set RLIMIT_NOFILE " << errno_ << std::endl;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
    event_base_new();
  }
}

This will eventually crash with
[err] evsignal_init: socketpair: Too many open files
libevent exit code: 1

I won't include it here, but we have a signal handler that reports this coming from a SIGABRT within
    @ 00000000025ca144 event_err
                       [...]/log.c:88
    @ 00000000025cc0e2 evsignal_init
                       [...]/signal.c:112
    @ 00000000025cb73b epoll_init
                       [...]/epoll.c:295
    @ 00000000025c8f41 event_base_new
                       [...]/event.c:192

Is there any way to prevent event_base_new from crashing the process and instead having it bubble up the error (eg. return NULL)? (Even if there's not much we can do about it.)

The documentation says it should return -1 if an error occurs, so it seems like this is a bug.

How big does i get?  Are you accounting for fds that are already opened (e.g., stdin, stdout, stderr)?  You could try using fcntl with F_GETFD to see which fds are in use, and which are available.

@Eljay I don't think the i really matters. This is a large application that involves fds from all over. But only this usage aborts the whole thing. The creation of the fd is internal to libevent too.

event_base_new should return NULL if it fails to allocate a new struct event_base. In any case, are you ever calling event_base_free to free up the resources allocated by each call to event_base_new?

@TedLyngmo Yeah, I don't think it's a resource leak like I think you're describing. The process is just doing A LOT.

@Savior So you are calling event_base_free on all pointers you get from calling event_base_new?

@TedLyngmo Yes.

@Savior Ok, so are the calls to event_base_new made asynchronously and, for whatever reason, your call to event_base_free for the first pointer comes too late, after 1024 more calls to event_base_new has been done (assuming each event_base_free requires a single file descriptor)? Or, are you storing a lot of struct event_base pointers to call event_base_free on them "later"?

@Savior It'd be good if you could setup a [mre] so that we can get an understanding of how you come to allocate so many file descriptors. Your current example doesn't call event_base_free at all. If you add a call to event_base_free in your loop, does it still run out of file descriptors?

@TedLyngmo Yes, this a within a large web server implementation. These objects are managed correctly (RAII, see folly::EventBase), there's just a lot of them (and a bunch of other things also requiring fds).

@TedLyngmo In other words, it is resource exhaustion and we can deal with it like the current answer suggests (increasing limits), but I'd also like for the process not to be forced to exit.

@Savior Then, instead of accepting more requests when you are not capable of handling them (because of the resource exhaustion) you could just wait until a previously allocated resource gets free'd. Count the number of folly::EventBases instances, block if they get close to the limit and wait until they number gets below a lower threshold.

Unfortunately the answer is no - there is no way to prevent libevent from calling exit(1) in that case.

1. libevent 1.x.x
1.1 API constraints
Note that in libevent 1.4.14 the function event_base_new can never return NULL - i.e. it either manages to create a new event base or exits the process:
event.h line 273:
/**
  Initialize the event API.

  Use event_base_new() to initialize a new event base, but does not set
  the current_base global.   If using only event_base_new(), each event
  added must have an event base set with event_base_set()

  @see event_base_set(), event_base_free(), event_init()
 */
struct event_base *event_base_new(void);

Note that there is no "If there is an error, it returns NULL" clause yet - that got added with libevent version 2.
So given that API constraint there really is no way to gracefully handle this - it either has to produce a fully functional event_base or die trying.
And if you check the implementation of event_base_new that is indeed the case - it always returns a non-null pointer or terminates:
event.c line 173:
struct event_base* event_base_new(void) {
    int i;
    struct event_base *base;

    if ((base = calloc(1, sizeof(struct event_base))) == NULL)
        event_err(1, "%s: calloc", __func__);

    // [...]

    base->evbase = NULL;
    for (i = 0; eventops[i] && !base->evbase; i++) {
        base->evsel = eventops[i];
        base->evbase = base->evsel->init(base);
    }

    if (base->evbase == NULL)
        event_errx(1, "%s: no event mechanism available", __func__);
    
    // [...]

    return (base);
}

Note: Both event_err and event_errx call exit unconditionally (the first parameter of those functions is the exit code that will be passed to exit)
1.2 Crash source
The error you encountered happened during evsignal_init().
The call stack was: (reconstructed from your backtrace)

event_base_new: base->evsel->init(base); (event.c line 197)
epoll_init: evsignal_init(base) (epoll.c line 149)
evsignal_init: event_err(1, "%s: socketpair", __func__); (signal.c line 112)
event_err: exit(eval); (log.c line 77)

Note that it does not matter that it was the epoll backend; all eventop backends (with the exception of kqueue - but that is FreeBSD / macOS specific) will call evsignal_init() without checking the return value.
This function is responsible for setting up signal handling for the event_base.
Note that this will result in event_err being called if evutil_socketpair fails (which in turn calls exit) (evutil_socketpair just forwards to socketpair on Linux)
int evsignal_init(struct event_base *base)
{
    int i;

    /* 
     * Our signal handler is going to write to one end of the socket
     * pair to wake up our event loop.  The event loop then scans for
     * signals that got delivered.
     */
    if (evutil_socketpair(
            AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, base->sig.ev_signal_pair) == -1) {
#ifdef WIN32
        /* Make this nonfatal on win32, where sometimes people
           have localhost firewalled. */
        event_warn("%s: socketpair", __func__);
#else
        event_err(1, "%s: socketpair", __func__);
#endif
        return -1;
    }

    // [...]

    return 0;
}

There is no magic flag to prevent it from terminating your process.
If it fails your process dies.

1.3 Patching it
If you feel comfortable building your own version of libevent you could work around this case by modifying its source code and recompiling it.
1.3.1 Dirty quickfix
The easy way out would be to comment out the event_err(1, "%s: socketpair", __func__); line within evsignal_init, e.g.:
if (evutil_socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, base->sig.ev_signal_pair) == -1) {
    return -1;
}

Note that this would have a few major drawbacks:

EV_EVENT becomes non-operational in case evsignal_init fails to allocate its socket pair.
=> probably fine as long as you don't try to call event_add with an event that has EV_EVENT specified.

In case the process actually ran out of file descriptors the event_base might choose a suboptimal backend.
Some backends (like poll, epoll, etc...) need to allocate a file descriptor to be operational.
If your process has no open file descriptors left then the only option libevent would have is to resort to using the select-based backend, which does not require an additional file descriptor.

(Benchmark taken from libevent.org)
But given that your process is out of file descriptors this probably won't matter.


1.3.2 Proper fix
To properly fix this so that event_base_new does not result in your process dying if there are no file descriptors left you would need to do a bit more work.

Like the quickfix above you would need to remove the event_err call from evsignal_init, so that it can fail gracefully.
You need to add code to all backends that use evsignal_init (devpoll, epoll, evport, poll, select, win32) to check the return value of evsignal_init, and if it returns -1 you would need extra code to cleanup the partially constructed eventop backend and return NULL, e.g. for epoll:
  static void* epoll_init(struct event_base *base) {
      int epfd;
      struct epollop *epollop;

      /* Disable epollueue when this environment variable is set */
      if (evutil_getenv("EVENT_NOEPOLL"))
          return (NULL);

      /* Initalize the kernel queue */
      if ((epfd = epoll_create(32000)) == -1) {
          if (errno != ENOSYS)
              event_warn("epoll_create");
          return (NULL);
      }

      FD_CLOSEONEXEC(epfd);

      if (!(epollop = calloc(1, sizeof(struct epollop))))
          return (NULL);

      epollop->epfd = epfd;

      /* Initalize fields */
      epollop->events = malloc(INITIAL_NEVENTS * sizeof(struct epoll_event));
      if (epollop->events == NULL) {
          free(epollop);
          return (NULL);
      }
      epollop->nevents = INITIAL_NEVENTS;

      epollop->fds = calloc(INITIAL_NFILES, sizeof(struct evepoll));
      if (epollop->fds == NULL) {
          free(epollop->events);
          free(epollop);
          return (NULL);
      }
      epollop->nfds = INITIAL_NFILES;

      //////// Original code ////////
      // evsignal_init(base);
      //////// Patched code  ////////
      if(!evsignal_init(base)) {
          free(epollop->fds);
          free(epollop->events);
          free(epollop);
          close(epfd);
          return NULL;
      }
      ////// End Patched code ///////

      return (epollop);
  }


You only need to patch those backends that you actually plan to use
In case of win32 (if you want to support that) you'll need to decide if you keep the existing logic (disable signal support if evsignal_init fails) or if you want to patch it so it also fails if evsignal_init fails.


Modify event_base_free so it can handle event_bases with no backend:
event.c
// Original code:
// if (base->evsel->dealloc != NULL)
//     base->evsel->dealloc(base, base->evbase);
// Modified code:
if (base->evsel != NULL && base->evsel->dealloc != NULL)
    base->evsel->dealloc(base, base->evbase);


Modify event_base_new so that it returns a NULL pointer if no eventop backend can be created instead of terminating the process (Warning: This is an API breaking change):
event.c
// Original code:
// base->evbase = NULL;
// for (i = 0; eventops[i] && !base->evbase; i++) {
//     base->evsel = eventops[i];
//     base->evbase = base->evsel->init(base);
// }
// if (base->evbase == NULL)
//     event_errx(1, "%s: no event mechanism available", __func__);
// Patched code:
base->evbase = NULL;
for (i = 0; eventops[i] && !base->evbase; i++) {
    base->evsel = eventops[i];
    base->evbase = base->evsel->init(base);
}
if (base->evbase == NULL) {
    base->evsel = NULL;
    event_base_free(base);
    return NULL;
}



Disclaimer: Code not tested. Might contain bugs.
That would more or less give you the behavior you expect (returning NULL on failure instead of crashing).
Note that in rare edge conditions you might still end up with the select eventop backend when epoll would be available (e.g. when there are no file descriptors available when libevent tries to create the epoll backend, but another thread or process frees 2 file descriptors before it reaches the select backend) - if that is a problem you can disable the select backend by setting the EVENT_NOSELECT environment variable. (and most likely poll as well)

2. libevent 2.0.x and 2.1.x
With libevent 2.0 and 2.1 the situation is unfortunately very similar.
evsignal_init has been renamed to evsig_init_, but the underlying behavior in case of no free file descriptors hasn't changed:
signal.c line 175
int evsig_init_(struct event_base *base)
{
    /*
     * Our signal handler is going to write to one end of the socket
     * pair to wake up our event loop.  The event loop then scans for
     * signals that got delivered.
     */
    if (evutil_make_internal_pipe_(base->sig.ev_signal_pair) == -1) {
#ifdef _WIN32
        /* Make this nonfatal on win32, where sometimes people
           have localhost firewalled. */
        event_sock_warn(-1, "%s: socketpair", __func__);
#else
        event_sock_err(1, -1, "%s: socketpair", __func__);
#endif
        return -1;
    }

    // [...]
}

event_sock_err calls event_exit which in turn calls exit or abort.
So to get the behavior you want you would still need to patch libevent.
You can skip the last two steps in "Proper fix" for these versions though (the event_base_new and event_base_free patches), because those versions already have that code present. (event_base_new can return NULL in libevent 2)
If you want to disable the select / poll backends to avoid accidentally getting those in low file descriptor scenarios you can use event_config_new() + event_config_avoid_method() + event_base_new_with_config() (see Setting up a complicated event_base).
(which is imho neater than the environment variables in 1.x)

3. libevent 2.2.x
libevent 2.2.1 is still in alpha, so technically not yet production ready. (at the time of this post)
If your target system supports signalfds (it probably does if it's not ancient - linux >= 2.6.22, glibc >= 2.8) then libevent will use them.
The signalfd implementation does not require a file descriptor on initialization, so it cannot fail in your case:
signalfd.c line 205
// fallback in evsignal-internal.h
// for the case that your target system does not support signalfds

#ifdef EVENT__HAVE_SYS_SIGNALFD_H
int sigfd_init_(struct event_base *);
#else /* no signalfd() */
static inline int
sigfd_init_(struct event_base *base) { return -1; }
#endif /* have signalfd() */

// actual implementation in signalfd.c
int sigfd_init_(struct event_base *base)
{
    EVUTIL_ASSERT(base != NULL);
    if ((base->flags & EVENT_BASE_FLAG_DISALLOW_SIGNALFD) ||
        getenv("EVENT_DISALLOW_SIGNALFD"))
        return -1;
    base->evsigsel = &sigfdops;
    return 0;
}

and the eventop backends now try to first initialize the signalfd implementation, and only if that fails they will fallback to evsig_init_:
if (sigfd_init_(base) < 0)
    evsig_init_(base);

Note that evsig_init_ has not changed compared to libevent 2.1; so if signalfds are not available (or explicitly disabled) then the old implementation will be used, which will exit your process if no file descriptor is available.
So for libevent 2.2:

If you're fine with using signalfds (and you only need to support non-ancient linux machines) then you don't have to do anything - it just works.
Otherwise you will have to apply the same patch as for libevent 2.0 / 2.1


4. Ending Words
There's one question I'd like to ask:

Why don't you just increase the limit of open file descriptors?

That would be a lot easier than trying to handle the out-of-file-descriptors case.
Because just like out-of-memory, out-of-file-descriptors is not easily handled if your program is not built for it (and just like OOM there are a lot of edge cases you need to cover)
The maximum number of file descriptors you can have per process (if you tweak the limits) is limited to 2147483647 (2**31-1).
(the global number of max file descriptors across all processes can be much larger than that (assuming you tweak the limits - with the upper bound being 9223372036854775807 (2**63-1))
Given that file descriptors do require a non-zero amount of RAM just to exist you'll probably run out of available memory before you even get close to 2147483647 file descriptors (if we guesstimate an average 1kb per file descriptor (most likely much more than that in a realistic program due to buffers associated with the fds) then you would need more than ~2TB of system RAM to reach the absolute file descriptor limit for a single process.
There are three limits that limit your file descriptors that you need to consider:

The process soft limit (as reported by ulimit -Sn)
Your process can't exceed its soft limit - once you hit it you will get the EMFILE error (out of file descriptors)
You can use setrlimit with RLIMIT_NOFILE to increase your process soft limit up to your hard limit (this does not require any additional permissions; you can always raise your soft limit up to the hard limit)
Example:
// increase soft limit to hard limit
struct rlimit lim;
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim);
lim.rlim_cur = lim.rlim_max;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim);


The process hard limit (as reported by ulimit -Hn)
This is the upper limit configured for your process.
This is either the global per-process limit (as reported by sysctl -n fs.nr_open) or a stricter limit imposed by yourself (setrlimit) or the process that created your process.
As a normal user you can only lower your hard-limit.
As root you can also raise your hard limit (up to fs.nr_open).
This can be manually raised up to 2147483647, usually by editing /etc/sysctl.conf (add fs.nr_open=2147483647 or whatever limit you want)

The global system limit (as reported by sysctl -n fs.file-max)
All processes running on the system can not request more than that many file descriptors in total.
If that limit is reached you will get the error ENFILE.
This can be manually raised up to 9223372036854775807, usually by editing /etc/sysctl.conf (add fs.file-max=9223372036854775807 or whatever limit you want)


On Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 (Jammy LTS) the defaults for those three limits are:

process soft limit: 1024
process hard limit: 1048576 (from fs.nr_open)
global system limit: 9223372036854775807

So out of the box you only get 1024 open file descriptors.
If you ask nicely using setrlimit you can increase that up to 1048576.
If you need even more than that you would need to tweak fs.nr_open (up to 2147483647 is possible)
